# Galois group of a polynomial

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I want to know how to find a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $5$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with Galois groups $G_f=\mathbb{S}_5$

Comment: Actually i find a criterion: that the polynomial should have exactly two complex roots,and be irreducible. But is a little hard to find such polynomial.
Also i was thinking that be irreducible and separable will work, but i can´t find anything about that, and neither and example of such polynomial

Comment: It's not that hard, think of the graph of the polynomial regarded as a real function, and try and apply Eisenstein's criterion, which you have surely seen.

Comment: Yes, thanks i have seen that.
Now i was thinking that if wouldnt be enough to be irreducible and be separable

Comment: It is not enough for the polynomial to be irreducible and separable. For example the minimal polynomial of $z=2\cos(2\pi/11)$ is quintic and separable. The field $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ is the real subfield of the eleventh cyclotomic field. The latter is of degree 10, so $[\mathbb{Q}(z):\mathbb{Q}]=5$. Therefore the Galois group is of order five, i.e. it must be cyclic.

Answer (score 6):

A standard approach is to construct an irreducible polynomial of degree $5$, which has three real roots, and two complex, non-real roots, which are then necessarily conjugate.

The fact that the polynomial is irreducible tells you that the Galois group, regarded as a group of permutation on the roots, is transitive on the roots, so that it has order divisible by $5$, and thus contains a $5$-cycle.

The fact about the roots tells you that complex conjugation is a $2$-cycle.

Now a $5$-cycle and a $2$-cycle generate $S_5$.

Comment: I know that  result, but i am looking for an example of such polynomial, but i don´t know hot to find it using that. 
Also i was thinking that if wouldnt be enough to be irreducible and be separable

Comment: @user62474 Every irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ is separable. At any rate you're correct that irreducible is insufficient, for instance $x^5-5$ is irreducible, by Eisenstein for instance. But its Galois group has order $20$, so cannot be $S_5$.

Comment: @JacobSchlather thanks for the answer, but can you tell me how to know that $x^{5}-5$ has galois group of order 20?

Comment: @user62474 Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $5$-th root of unity then the splitting field of $x^5-5$ is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[5]{5},\zeta)$. Since $\zeta$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt[5]{5}$ has degree $5$ it follows that their composite extension must have degree $20$ since it is divisible by $5$ and $4$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \rm X^5 + 10 \, X^2 - 5$$

is irreducible by Eisenstein, and [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20x%5E5%20%2b%2010x%5E2%20-%205) says it has three real roots.